# Road Network with 4th & 5th road level (small agriculture roads & footpaths)

Tags: data, network, road, transportation, navigation

I have a need to use 4th & 5th level roads (small agriculture roads & footpaths) for Germany and the only provider I could find is the Logiball.

Is anybody aware of another provider?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: I have edited the question!

Answer (score 3):

OSM has a good coverage of agriculture/forestry roads ([highway=track](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dtrack)) and foot paths ([highway=footway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dfootway), [highway=path](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dpath), [highway=bridleway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dbridleway), [highway=cycleway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dcycleway)), especially in Germany. Just take a look at the map of your area.

Comment: I am personally using OSM regularly and I completely trust them. Nevertheless, how could I know the reliability of OSM? Up to which level are OSM accurate enough to be used in a commercial application?

Comment: In OSM this depends on the geographic region and the local community. How can you know the reliability of other maps?

Comment: I believe the same exactly. This is a conversation I have all the time with colleagues. The only argument they have on that: "when you pay for a product, you expect high quality and support...". Thanks for your feedback!